# Check if array is123

Tags: java, arrays

I want to write a method to check if an array is123, is123 is an array that has a multiple repetition sequence of integers 1,  2,  3. Int [] arr1 = {1,  2,  3,  1,  2,  3} should return 1 because arr1 is123 otherwise return 0.

Examples -
int [] arr = {1,  1,  2,  3} should return 0.
int [] arr = {1,  2,  3,  0,  1,  2,  3} should return 0.
int [] arr = {1,  2,  3} should return 1.Please help me solve this problem using a brute force approach only, thanks for your help in advance. This was my poor attempt.

```
public static int is123Array(int[] a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
       if (a[i] == 1 && a[i + 1] == 2 && a[i + 2] == 3) {
             return 1;
        }
      }
         return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Are you able to use `Arrays.equals`? That would simplify your code somewhat.

Comment: Yes, i can use Arrays.equals. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Your implementation is close!

You need to increment `i` by `3` instead of by `1`, as you're checking indices `i`, `i + 1`, and `i + 2` during each iteration.

You're also returning early inside your if-statement; an array of `[1, 2, 3, 4]` would return `1`, because it returns after finding the first triple of `[1, 2, 3]`. To fix this, you should return `0` if you **don't** find a triple of `[1, 2, 3]`, as then you can be certain that the array is not a solution.

Your fixed up code might look something like this:

```
public static int is123Array(int[] a) {
    // If the length of the array is 0 or not a multiple of 3, then
    // you know it isn't a solution.
    if (a.length == 0 || a.length % 3 != 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i += 3) {
        if (a[i] != 1 || a[i + 1] != 2 || a[i + 2] != 3) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

I also recommend returning a `boolean` instead of an `int`, as the only possible return values are `0` and `1`, denoting `false` and `true`, respectively.